# Powershell scripts to get the FIPS algorithm status

Tags: powershell, sockets, sslstream

I am looking for the powershell scripts/commands to get the details of below points
| Key                            | OutPut           |
| ------------------------------ | ---------------- |
| Seurity [FIPS Alogithm Policy] | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Client SSL 2.0 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Server SSL 2.0 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Client SSL 3.0 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Server SSL 3.0 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Client TLS 1.1 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Server TLS 1.1 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Client TLS 1.2 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |
| Is Server TLS 1.2 Enabled?     | Enabled/Disabled |

I have tried the below code but getting different different errors.

```
$Socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket([System.Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Stream, [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp)
$Socket.Connect($ComputerName, $Port)
$NetStream = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream($Socket, $true)
$SslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($NetStream, $true)
$SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($ComputerName, $null, $ProtocolName, $false)
```

I have Sql Server 2014 installed with the latest updates.

I am looking for the Correct Powershell scripts to get the details for the FIPS Algorithm status and the status of protocol (SSL and TLS) for client/server.
I tried the above code but its not working.

Comment: What errors exactly?

Comment: Are you [actually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) trying to find out which encryption protocols are supported by the SQL Server installation?

Comment: Will share the error today. @marsze. Earlier it was "Connection Rejected by host" but now it says that "Algorithm do not match".

Comment: @vonPryz:- Yes, I want to know whether FIPS algorith is enabled for SQL Server and SSRS both and then want to know the details of protocols (SSL and TLS) client / server  is enabled or disabled.